# How do I test an angular dart decorator?

Tags: dart, karma-runner, angular-dart

I am trying to unit test an angular dart decorator but cannot pass the component compile phase.

I am trying to follow this example : https://github.com/vsavkin/angulardart-sample-app/blob/master/test/unit/agenda_item_component_test.dart

The problem is that karma doesn't seem to wait for the compile phase to finish and just skips the test.

```dart
part of webpuzzle_spec;

digest() {
  inject((TestBed tb) {
    tb.rootScope.apply();
  });
}

compileComponent(String html, Map scope, callback) {
  print("This logs");
  return async(() {
    inject((TestBed tb) {
      print("this should log but doesn't");
      final s = tb.rootScope.createChild(scope);
      final el = tb.compile(html, scope: s);
      microLeap();

      digest();

      callback(el.shadowRoot);
    });
  });
}

testWpDropdownMenu() {

  group("[WpDropdownMenu]", () {

    setUp(setUpInjector);
    tearDown(tearDownInjector);

    setUp((){
      module((Module _) => _..type(TestBed)..type(WpDropdownMenu));
    });

    html() => '''<span class="dropdown-toggle">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">menu to click</button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>menu item</li>
                  </ul>
                </span>''';

    test("should open menu on click", compileComponent(html(), {}, (shadowRoot) {
      print("this never logs :(");
      shadowRoot.click();
      digest();
      var toggleableMenu = shadowRoot.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
      expect(toggleableMenu.style.display, equals('none'));
      expect(true, equals(false)); // this should make the test fail
    }));

  });
}
```

What is the problem with this code ? Is there a nice example somewhere that explains how to test a component/decorator, only using angular.dart and karma ?

Comment: It's a while since I did it. I guess you should find several examples here https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui